# How to copy my project code to Jenkins Container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to run my test in Jenkins Container which is running in my mac. I installed SCM System File plugin in my Jenkins container to copy the workspace of my project code from host to Jenkins Workspace of Jenkins Container.

But I am getting error as:

```
FSSCM.checkout /Users/userTest/Documents/personal/regression/ to 
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/regression-test
FATAL: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory

Comment: What is the value of the parameter baseResourcesGeneratedDirectory in your task ?

Comment: Where I can check this?

Comment: Are you using WebLogic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue, by creating a network with volume mounting.

Note: Directory also needs to have all privileged (Read/Write)